# How to get past this duplicate symbol error (Vungle, CodePush)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-push, vungle-ads

How do I get past this error?

```
duplicate symbol _zipOpen4 in:
    /Users/a/app/app-client/ios/Pods/VungleSDK-iOS/VungleSDK.embeddedframework/VungleSDK.framework/VungleSDK(vungle_zip.o)
    /Users/a/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppClient-hirdjpuiiuosayehatqakfrifyvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCodePush.a(zip.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate symbol is fairly generic and co-relates to many things. In this case

There could be three reasons. Vungle and CodePush might be using same constant names. Or Vungle may internally be using CodePush or vice-versa.

Try to include only one in them and see if it works. Chances are that you might be using both libraries in same interface/implementation if so try splitting code into multiple files.

Comment: Hi, yes this occurs as I'm adding Vungle, so it works with just CodePush, but of course I can't get the ads unless I add Vungle.